# React Native "The expo SDK requires Expo to run. .... this code is not running on Expo."

Tags: reactjs, native, react-native, expo

I am coding with React Native. I don't see that when I first create react-native app for check running. When I implements my code see that. My purpose is generate apk.

[image]

- [app.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZlVq.png)
- [build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgYti.png)
- [index.js (index.android.json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG05J.png)
- [App package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRYau.png)

---

## Solved

**Result: I solved my problem with npm install. I would like say many month after.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html

If you want to use expo in your application, you must create it in the following way

`npm i -g create-react-native-app
create-react-native-app my-project
cd my-project
npm start`

*This will start the React Native packager and print a QR code. Open it in the Expo app to load your JavaScript.*

as I see your code has files that are not necessary, such as build.gradle and index.js, the structure that **create-react-native-app** creates is different and easier to use

Comment: Thank your feedback but I don't wanna use expo. I am trying Android Studio for generate apk. I search but I didn't find a result for my problem. Do you suggest any tag, concept, type for learn?
I tried react native generating apk of offical document.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone's getting this error after upgrading Expo, try restarting your simulator - that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my experience if someone using expo sees those error message.

I accidentally installed expo manually in my project which was version 29.0.0.

I was using version 28.0.0 of expo sdk, so it may have crashed inside.

What I did:

1. manually upgrade sdkVersion of app.json to 29.0.0.
2. change sdk version to 29.0.0 for react-native.

Comment: Just had exactly this problem: I had upgraded to 29.0.0 in package.json, but not app.json.  (app.json really should read from package.json...)

Answer (score 3):

Had exactly the same error - fresh machine, fresh npm, only one version of expo installed.

Turns out, expo requires you to build it as an app before it can send it to the expo app properly (at least on Android). This is easiest done by:

- Adding an "android" section to app.json, with the contents `"package": "uk.co.yourcompany.yourpackagename"` (this is required by android packages. It can be complete garbage, but should follow that format - a backwards domain name)
- running `expo build:android` and following the instructions to sign up to expo's servers and build the app
- then restarting `expo start`

Not sure if this is documented anywhere though, so may be a new thing?

Another thing to try is to move your `node_modules` folder away (or maybe delete it, up to you) and re-run `npm install`

Comment: Pretty weird, but going through this did fix the issue for me as well

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after updating the `expo-cli` to version `3.0.6`.

By looking at my `package.json` I noticed the `expo-cli` version installed on my computer is not the same as `package.json`. so I changed it to `"expo-cli": "^3.0.6"` and ran `npm install || yarn`, then the error disappeared!